# Spring Boot - how to get a class annotated with @Service by it's name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I'm quite new to spring (switching from PHP to Java).

In my code I have a `java.lang.reflect.Method` objects and I need to instantiate it's class with all it's dependencies.

Normally I'd use `@Autowired` annotation in my code, but it's not possible because my code gets different Method objects, not specific classes.

Question is - how to get a class instance from dependency container without using annotations and having just class name?

In php i used libraries which gave me access to container and I could just get DI services by it's class name just like:

```
$this->container->get('My\Class\Name');
```

In spring I tried:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;
void myMethod(Method method){
this.context.getBean(method.getClass());
```

and

```
this.context.getBean(method.getClass().getName());
```

and that was resulting in `NullPointerException`.

EDIT
Thanks for quick replys,

I tried using

```
context.getBean(method.getDeclaringClass());
```

and

```
context.getBean(method.getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName());
```

And it both resulted in NullPointerException as well.

Actually it's okay for my needs to get that class by class or by name. I'm trying to write my own command bus for CQRS.
Let me show you some code:

Handler:

```
public class SimpleCommandBus implements CommandBus {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    private Map<Class, Method> registry = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void register(Class c, Method o) {
        registry.put(c, o);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispatch(Object command) {
        if (!registry.containsKey(command.getClass())) {
            throw new CommandDispatchException(String.format("Handler for command %s was not defined.", command));
        }

        Method method = registry.get(command.getClass());
        Object handler = context.getBean(method.getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName());//line causing exception
```

Service class:

```
@Service
public class TestHandler {

    public void handle(TestCommand command){
        System.err.println(command.getId());
    }
}
```

Calling command bus:

```
    Method method = TestHandler.class.getMethod("handle", TestCommand.class);
    TestCommand command = new TestCommand("Test command");
    commandBus.register(TestCommand.class, method);
    commandBus.dispatch(command);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`java.lang.reflect.Method.getDeclaringClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getDeclaringClass()) to find in which class the given method is declared. `method.getClass()` will return the type of `method` object which is `java.lang.reflect.Method`.

```
@Autowired
AplicationContext ctx;

...

Object bean = ctx.getBean(method.getDeclaringClass());
```

Comment: That may also work but the question was "get ... by its name"

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. I've added some code in question edit to clarify

Comment: @MateuszWu Spring will produce proxies for the beans e.g. to support the `@Transactional`. What does `method.getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName()` return?

Comment: System.err.println(method.getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName()); 
returns "TestHandler" @KarolDowbecki

Comment: In addition - i also checked if i can autowire that service (TestHandler) to make sure that spring DI can see it and it works perfectly.

Comment: @MateuszWu since the error is in `SimpleCommandBus.java:31` it feels like either `method` or `context` are null. As per your example nothing else in this line can produce NPE and the problem seems unrelated to Spring.

Comment: I've just found out that context is null, but it has @Autowired annotation - that makes me confused. Why isn't it autowiring? That leads to conclusion that it probably is a spring-related problem

Comment: @MateuszWu most likely you have created `new SimpleCommandBus()` instead of making `SimpleCommandBus` bean with `@Service` or `@Component` annotation.

Comment: It turned out that i was missing @Autowired annotation over commandBus. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring the default name is the simple name.

Plus as in Karols answer you must use getDeclaringClass() to get the class of the class with the method.

So you must call

```
this.context.getBean(method.getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName());
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. I've added some code in question edit to clarify

Comment: Can you please add the stacktrace of the exception you get?